# Long distance cable to monoblock centrifugal pump from PV VFD

Tags: solar-cell, vfd, system

I want to install a three phase 10 HP monoblock centrifugal pump that is around 200 meters away from the PV solar Vfd. The solar system is installed with 16 solar panels of jinko 555 p type. I would like to understand what cable/wire thickness I would need to opt to minimize voltage drop and proper working of the said pump.

Comment: The cable size depends on the current being conducted. You didn't specify the voltage required by your pump nor the current so an answer cannot be given. Also you need to specify how much voltage drop you can tolerate over the 200 meter run. You should also specify how the cable is to be run: above or below ground, in a conduit, etc. All of these factors need to be combined to allow a reasonable choice of cable size. Cost will also have to be considered since a 200 meter cable that can power a 10 HP pump (which will draw close to 10,000 watts) will be expensive.

Comment: my apologies, I though voltage was same for every 3 phase application. So the voltage requirement of the pump is  380 v and 16 amps i believe.  Cable can be run above or underground, both are fine but  I am really thinking long term so would like losses to be minimum.